Why is my constructor telling me that a field must contain a non-null value when I am assigning it in the constructor but through a property?
In my class, I set the value of _owner indirectly in the constructor through the Owner property. However, the compiler still thinks that a value will not be assigned by the end of the constructor. The property that I used to assign the backing field already does the null check. Why is this warning happening, and how can I fix it?
public class BankAccount
{
    private string _owner;

    // Warning: Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when 
    // exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable
    public BankAccount(string owner)
    {
        // The compiler warning is gone if I check the values here,
        // but this leads to code duplication.
        this.Owner = owner;
    }

    public string Owner
    {
        get
        {
            return _owner;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Owner name you want to set is null");
            }
            _owner = value;
        }
    }
}


I hope someone can prove me wrong, but I'm pretty sure the simple answer is that the nullability analyzer of the C# compiler just does not support this scenario. After all, static code anaysis is hard and adding complexity to the compiler is only done if the benefit is worth the cost.

How exactly does your line BankAccount b = new BankAccount(.....) look like ?  (Please provide a [mre]!)

A simple (but not very pretty) workaround would be private string _owner = null!; // constructor calls the setter with null check.

I've helped you out by making your question title, body, and code more clear and more of a [mre]. If you think it's too much or incorrect, roll it back. See [ask].

Try the following: private string _owner = string.Empty;.

The C# compiler does not do a full analysis of all setters and methods called in the constructor, so it needs your help here. This will tell it that the Owner setter ensures that _owner is non-null (sharplab):
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
...

public string Owner
{
    get
    {
        ...
    }
    [MemberNotNull(nameof(_owner))]
    set
    {
        ...
    }
}

Another alternative would be to replace Owner with an auto-generated property and rely on C#'s NRT analysis instead of a runtime check.

Thank you, I have been looking for something like this.

What you can do, providing you resort to C# 12 or later, is to declare your class with new constructor syntax, like so:
public class BankAccount(string owner, decimal balance)
{
     public string Owner { get; } = owner;
     public decimal Balance { get; } = balance;

     public override string ToString() => $"Owner: {Owner}, Balance: {Balance}";
}


For the record, the "new constructor syntax" is called "Primary Constructors", and by using auto-properties this removes the custom set logic from the original code.

Thank you for the answer. The point of the question is in checking value in setter. If I did like you I cannot check for null value in setter.
